# Error 403 forbidden , req.body recibe objeto vacio

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

estoy haciendo un boton para eliminar una publicación especifica y solo el usuario que la realizo la podra eliminar, para ello tengo el siguiente controlador

```
export const deletePost = async ( req, res ) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const { userId } = req.body;

    try {
        const post =await PostModel.findById(id);
        if (post.userId === userId) {
            await post.deleteOne();
            res.status(200).json("Post Deleted successfully");
        }else {
            res.status(403).json("Action forbidden");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
};
```

La ruta es

```
router.delete('/:id/delete', deletePost);
```

En el boton tengo una función la cual hace el `dispatch` a mi accion el cual es la siguiente

```
const handleDelete = () => {
    dispatch( deletePost(user._id,data) );
    setMenuOpened(false);
  };
```

Donde allí tengo la acción donde recibo los parametros y envio a mi `request`

```
export const deletePost = (id, data) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "RETREIVING_START" });
  try {

    const deletePost = await PostApi.deletePost(data._id, id);
    dispatch({ type: "RETREIVING_SUCCESS", data: deletePost.data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({ type: "RETREIVING_FAIL" });
  }
};
```

En mi `request`, recibo los parametros y los envio

```
export const deletePost = ( id, userId ) => API.delete(`/post/${ id }/delete`, { userId: userId  });
```

El problema es que en el `backend` cuando trato de sacar el `id` del usuario por medio del `body` para hacer la validación de si el usuario es el que creo la publicación me sale que recibe un `{}`

Alguna solución para ello? gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás usando el analizador del cuerpo de la solicitud? (`body parser`). En Express, antes de declarar tus rutas debes agregar: `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true});` y además: `app.use(express.json());`. De lo contrario el objeto `body` siempre estará vacío. Saludos

Comment: Si, incluso ya he hecho otros metodos sacando datos de mi objeto body pero en este no entiendo el error

Comment: ¿Has revisado la solicitud en el navegador? ¿Sabes si efectivamente la solicitud tiene el valor esperado en el `body`?

Comment: En que parte puedo ver eso?

Comment: Con las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador. Dependiendo del navegador serán algo diferentes, pero todas tienen lo básico para ver la solicitud. Chrome developer tools o DevTools de Firefox. O las del navegador que estés usando.

Comment: Allí entre a la pestaña network y me sale lo siguiente `Request URL: http://localhost:5000/post/637e6b88ea3149ccfe9cae74/delete`, el error 403 y mas cosas, el id que se ve en ese url es el id de la publicación la cual esta bien